# prevent npm from rebuilding everything every time

Tags: npm

Since I added a dependency to my react project `npm run build` always takes a very long time. I guess that it always rebuilds everything completely.

Can I just add something to the command to tell it to just take the result from last time for this dependency and not rebuild it again?